# Can we Ask Question to people for their ideas on something

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I wonder if i can ask public about their ideas related to Android. This can be a consulting such an; how better i can attract users, is button or image better to be used in this layout, how i can manage this better and so on.

It is all about encouraging people commenting and giving suggestions to user who asked question.

Comment: That sounds like the very definition of an opinionated question, so no.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of question is very likely to be off-topic here - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, but not all at once, and not on Stack Overflow. Each of those questions has a different context.

How can I attract users?
Too broad anywhere

Is button or image better to be used in this layout?
[UX Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

How can I manage this better?
Potentially opinion based. Perhaps code review

Answer (score 6):

No, Stack Overflow is for questions and answers about specific programming problems, or specific issues with the application or tool environments.  It isn't for discussion on ideas.  There are many other sites out there you can do that on.

Answer (score 4):

None of your example questions seem to be a good fit for Stack Overflow.

> How better I can attract users?

This isn't a programming question.  In addition, there are too many answers or answers would be too long for the Q&A format.  You're probably looking for a book on SEO.

> Is button or image better to be used in this layout?

This looks like a matter of opinion.

> How I can manage this better?

This sounds way too broad for Stack Overflow.  Given a lot more details it *might* be suitable for a Stack Exchange site, but it's impossible to say from this short snippet of a question.